# Error With Git Tab Completion: "python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2]"

Tags: python, git, bash, shell, autocomplete

When I try to tab complete git commands, I receive this python error. Sometimes, it will still complete the command (but after the 3 lines of Python errors), and sometimes it does the following. Git and bash-completion are at their latest versions. I'm running Ubuntu 13.04. How can I get rid of this error?

```
[~/code]$ git co[TAB]python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
^C

[~/code]$ sudo apt-get install bash-completion
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
bash-completion is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

[~/code]$ sudo apt-get install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version.
git set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 0):

`manage.py` is from Django, not git. It sounds like you have installed Django bash completion, but not Django itself (or maybe it's in a virtualenv that you have not activated).

Comment: How can I disable Django bash completion? Why is it running in a folder without a Django project? I do have Django installed.